# Exporting text for a question to pdf even if it required a manual copy and paste

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Just wondering if some one has found a simple and for free, way to convert text with lots of tex equations typed for this website into pdf file or a word file with appropriate equation formatting.

Hopefully better than what was suggested in [similar question from 4 months ago](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/is-it-possible-to-convert-and-possibly-download-the-answers-discussions-in-pdf)
It would save me a lot of trouble to be able to export this text.

Cheers
Hardy

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of the earlier question?

Comment: Well for one i do not want necessarily the whole thread, i am just after the ability to copy and paste a text snippet from a question or an answer into a tool and be able to convert that text into apdf without needing to manually format every equation. Secondly i do n't see, there being anything wrong about creating a duplicate 4 months later obviously this is n't maths that the rules are timeless, maybe some one has found an external tool since the last time, which they found helpfull in accomplishing this task.

Comment: Click edit, copy and paste to a text editor, manually rewrite `_blah_` to `\emph{blah}`, run `pdflatex` on the snippet?

Comment: What do you mean by "appropriate equation formatting"? Do you just mean that you want it to look right, or are you after being able to copy and paste it from the pdf? (If the former, I have a very simple method: I press Ctrl-P and print to PDF).

Comment: I was thinking the former . Thanks guys so much great suggestions indeed.

Comment: See also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15163/save-the-answer-in-pdf